# InvalidCastException on a list of objects

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a query whose results look like

```
Blue
OrangeRed
Black
Green
Silver
Red
```

I intend to make a list of System.Drawing.Color objects out of this result set.  When I run the program I'm getting the InvalidCastException.  All of those colors are definitely in the enum of Color.  Why am I getting this exception?

```
private List<System.Drawing.Color> BuildColorList()
    {
        List<System.Drawing.Color>ColorList = new List<System.Drawing.Color>();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select color from Colors", con))
            {
                con.Open();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    System.Drawing.Color color = (System.Drawing.Color)rdr["color"];
                    ColorList.Add(color);
                }
            }
            return ColorList;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You cannot directly cast the result of the SqlDataReader to `System.Drawing.Color`. Use the `FromName` method instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot do a cast: the query returns a `System.String` object, which cannot be cast to a `System.Drawing.Color` directly. Instead, you need to use [`Color.FromName(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.fromname.aspx) method instead:

```
private List<System.Drawing.Color> BuildColorList()
{
    List<System.Drawing.Color>ColorList = new List<System.Drawing.Color>();
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select color from Colors", con))
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                System.Drawing.Color color = System.Drawing.Color.FromName((string)rdr["color"]);
                ColorList.Add(color);
            }
        }
        return ColorList;
    }
}
```

Comment: @NikolaMitev You're right, I linked the right doc, but I typed the name incorrectly. This is now fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Replace this

```
System.Drawing.Color color = (System.Drawing.Color)rdr["color"];
```

with this

```
 System.Drawing.Color color =Color.FromName((string)rdr["color"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't just cast a string (which is what is being returned from the database query) to an instance of `System.Drawing.Color`.

Instead, you should use something like [`System.Drawing.Color.FromName()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.fromname.aspx) to parse the color:

```
System.Drawing.Color color = 
    System.Drawing.Color.FromName(rdr["color"] as string);
```

Comment: This probably won't work without casting the argument to `string`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing a cast use the `FromName` method;

```
System.Drawing.Color color = Color.FromName(rdr["color"]);
```

will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
System.Drawing.Color color = Color.FromName( (string)rdr["color"] );
```